# Show and Hide an element (status bar) when Ajax request starts and finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a form to upload photos via Ajax, the status bar appears when you start the request and is working properly. The problem is that when the request is over, the bar remains active and thumbnail photo appears. The bar should reappear if another request is made.

I would like to hide the bar when the request is finished, and tried several things but none of them worked, this is my code:

```
   //jQuery Ajax to Post form data
   $.ajax({
    url : post_url,
    type: "POST",
    data : form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    xhr: function(){
     //upload Progress
     var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
     if (xhr.upload) {
      xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
       var percent = 0;
       var position = event.loaded || event.position;
       var total = event.total;
       if (event.lengthComputable) {
        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
       }
       //update progressbar
       $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", + percent +"%");
       $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent +"%");
      }, true);
     }
     return xhr;
    },
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data"
   }).done(function(res){ //
    $(my_form_id)[0].reset(); //reset form
    $(result_output).html(res); //output response from server
    submit_btn.val("Enviar").prop( "disabled", false); //enable submit button once ajax is done
   });
```

This is the HTML code to display the progress bar:

```
<div id="progress-wrp">
 <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this   $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("display", "none");

Comment: use `$(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").fadeOut()` on loaded

Comment: @FerasSalim Trying ... bar disappears forever (at start and end) ... it does not work.

Comment: if it's still in your dom, you can show it at the beginning of your request.

Comment: you should add this line when the progress 100% completed, add it in done function @GePraxa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try?
Did you try a hide() at the bottom of your done() method? (this also show()s it when the request is made)

`$("#progress-wrp").show();` gets the element by it's id using jquery and shows it (in this case when the request is starts).

`$("#progress-wrp").hide();` gets the element by it's id using jquery and hides it (in this case when the request is done()).

```
xhr: function(){
     //upload Progress
     $("#progress-wrp").show();
     var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
     if (xhr.upload) {
      xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
       var percent = 0;
       var position = event.loaded || event.position;
       var total = event.total;
       if (event.lengthComputable) {
        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
       }
       //update progressbar
       $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", + percent +"%");
       $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent +"%");
      }, true);
     }
     return xhr;
    },
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data"

    .done(function(res){ //
        $(my_form_id)[0].reset(); //reset form
        $(result_output).html(res); //output response from server
        submit_btn.val("Enviar").prop( "disabled", false); //enable submit button once ajax is done
       $("#progress-wrp").hide();
       });
```